# WPF Highlight background when dragged over

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have successfully implemented drag and drop in my application. An am now working on improving the user experience.

My aim is when a drag starts to highlight my possible targets, and then if they are dragged over change to a different colour.

I came up with this which *almost* works, however it seems to sometimes miss the DragLeave Event. The style is applied to any of my controls that are being used as a drop target (multiple types)

```
<Style x:Key="HighlightDrop">
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Orange" /> <!-- usually set to transparent, just set to orange here to make it obvious-->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.DragEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Highlight">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame Value="LightGreen" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.DragLeave">
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Highlight" />
        </EventTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AmDragging, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="LightBlue" />
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I then tried a different approach, but this didn't work wither as it appears that the IsMouseOver event doesn't work during dragging.

```
<Style x:Key="HighlightDrop">
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Orange" />
    <!-- usually set to transparent, just set to orange here to make it obvious-->
    <Style.Triggers>

        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding AmDragging, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" Value="True" > <!-- Just used to test that the binding for IsMouseOver is working -->
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AmDragging, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="LightBlue" />
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

What am I missing here, it feels like I am re-inventing the wheel when the job should be pretty basic to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

drag and drop works is quite hard to understand and annoying thing.
drag event sometimes is consumed by another control.
especially, if your xaml page has content control. content control has `PreviewDragEnter`, `PreviewDragLeave`, `PreviewDragOver`. you should call following source code when its event fired. `e.Handled = true`.
In my case, I was about to move ListBox Item ordering with drag and drop interaction. ListBox Item contains `TextBox`, `ComboBox` wich is IsEditable=true, and `ContentControl`. those controls were consuming drag leave event when mouse is over it while drag leaving. so I called `e.Handled = true`. on `PreviewDragEnter`, `PreviewDragLeave`, `PreviewDragOver` event of those controls.

Comment: Hello, I dont quite follow this sorry, how will handling the event early help in this case, and how do I do that from XAML.